# Is it possible to reverse a list with only two arguments?

Tags: list, prolog

Is it possible to reverse a list in Prolog with only two arguments? Such as:

```
reverse_list(List, Reversed).
```

This is not homework, I'm reading Seven Programming Languages in Seven Weeks and I got curious.

With three arguments you could use an accumulator (much like in functional programming):

```
reverseList([], Accumulator, Accumulator).
reverseList([Head|Tail], Accumulator, Solution) :-
  reverseList(Tail, [Head|Accumulator], Solution).
reverseList(List, Solution) :-
  reverseList(List, [], Solution).
```

**Clarification**: I saw a solution with append, I was wondering if you could do that without other prolog functions

Comment: Please don't put pseudo-tags in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure:

```
reverseList([[], Accumulator, Accumulator]).
reverseList([[Head|Tail], Accumulator, Solution]) :-
  reverseList([Tail, [Head|Accumulator], Solution]).
reverseList([List, Solution]) :-
  reverseList([List, [], Solution]).
```

edit:actually that has only one :b

a non-cheating approach:

```
reverse([],[]).
reverse([H|T],L):-
    reverse(T,R),
    append(R,[H],L).
```

the problem is that the performance will be quite bad: you will recurse over the list and for each element you will do one append/3.
using time/1 and a random list of 1,000,000 elements:

```
accumulator:    % 2,000,003 inferences, 0.652 CPU in 0.652 seconds (100% CPU, 3066292 Lips)
arity-2         % 1,000,003 inferences, 0.178 CPU in 0.178 seconds (100% CPU, 5602426 Lips)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a `rev_list` function with two arguments:

```
rev_list([], []).
rev_list([Head|Tail], Reversed) :- rev_list(Tail, TailReversed), 
                                       append(TailReversed, [Head], Reversed).
```

Maybe you are more familiar with this function if it is in functional programming:

```
rev x::xs = rev xs @ [x]
```

However, you should notice that the 3-argument version is preferred because it is tail-recursive.

Comment: I saw a solution with append, I was wondering if you could do that without other prolog functions.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party, but there is a way to do this without "cheating" or using `append`:

```
rev([], []).
rev([Head], [Head]).
rev([Head|Tail], [RHead|RTail]) :-
  rev(Tail, [RHead|RMid]),
  rev(RMid, Mid),
  rev([Head|Mid], RTail).
```

It is not very efficient (`O(3^n)` time), but it is elegant and can even be useful for theorem proving.

Comment: @repeat Because it does not use any external functions, so it is really easy to see what it does. I took a class that used [ACL2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL2) and I remember that we made ACL2 prove that this version is equivalent to the append version and to the tail recursive version. Then we could use the efficient tail recursive one in our programs, but have ACL2 replace it with this one or the append one (depending on which was more convenient) when proving the program's correctness.